# set WORKDIR using pattern

Tags: docker, workdir

Is there a way to change the WORKDIR to the first pattern matched folder? something like

```
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
RUN pattern=mypattern*
RUN files=( $pattern )
WORKDIR $files
```

Unlike my local terminal behaviour the files variable remains empty, eventhough the current WORKDIR is correct and the folder most certainly exists based on docker buil logs.

EDIT: for clarification, the use case is:

There is a Go package (lilliput) which comes with prebuilt binaries, but these binaries don't work on the platform our docker imagine will be running on. Thankfully this package provides a `build_deps.sh` for such cases, but this has to be executed from the package installation folder. This folder will have a arbitrary name based on the package release version (eg `lilliput@v0.0.0-20210720001558-e1547514bd5f` )
The Goal is to pattern match this folder and `lilliput*`, switch the WORKDIR and start the dependency build there.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use ENV variables, or args on buiild docker file

Comment: thanks but this doesnt really solve the issue as i am changing WORKDIR to compile some binaries for an extrenal Golang Package which might end up under `packagenamev23o4h2u3hr9h34hr92h3792h3` depending on the release